# Create Custom Long-Nook Notification on WatchOS side

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, watchkit, watchos-2

Is it possible to customize the buttons of a dynamic long nook notification from the watch-side?. The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW5://) shows an example on iOS side and making use of UIApplication which I believe is not a  availavable on the watch side. I can't found any data regarding this matter on the web nor in the official documentation and I'm not sure if this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to customize the buttons of a dynamic long nook notification from the watch-side?

No, it is not possible to change the look of the buttons of a dynamic long look notification.

You can change what buttons appear (0 to 4 buttons are possible) by setting the notification category in the companion phone app. Notification category cannot be set in the watch app.

See the [WatchKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH6-SW1) for more details.